Does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point when running docker build
Does not contain a static 'main' method suitable for an entry point
using CountryAPI.Models;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICountryService, CountryService>(); // Singleton service

        var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1"); });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();

    }
}

Program runs in Visual Studio but shows CSC 5001 error when using docker build command in terminal.

Tried changing the output type to exe
Made sure program was in compile mode
Added a main method
Restarted everything

Dockerfile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0-nanoserver-1809 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["CountryAPI.csproj", "CountryAPI/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./CountryAPI/./CountryAPI.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/CountryAPI"
RUN dotnet build "./CountryAPI.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./CountryAPI.csproj" -c %BUILD_CONFIGURATION% -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CountryAPI.dll"] 


What does the dockerfile look like? Did you make the dockerfile or was this generated by Visual Studio?

It was generated by VS

Changing OutputType in .csproj to Library worked
<OutputType>Library</OutputType>

It allows docker to build but debug "run" shows error.
Docker run shoes error "hostpolicy.dll" not found.
